# Using @RouteConfig, is it possible prevent browser's address bar from being changed?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

With this `@RouteConfig` --> Is it possible to prevent browser's address bar stay as "http://foo.com/" where "/" stay as "/" and never append the "/Home" to browser's address bar at all?  Angular pass around the url internally on the same webpage so why should browser's address bar not change?

We don't want the customer to keep using the web browser's back button and mess up webpage data.

```
@RouteConfig([
    {
        path: '/',
        name: 'SignIn',
        component: SignInComponent,
        useAsDefault: true
    },
    {
        path: '/', //Home',
        name: 'Home',
        component: MemberHomeComponent
    }
])
```

Comment: I believe the main point of routing is the changing url, browser history and ability to go to a particular url and have a particular component loaded. Probably better off using another technique?

Comment: Router works purely based on the browser URL, I think what you are expecting is not possible to achieve with angular2 router.

Comment: Routing is supposed to work with urls. [**DynamicComponentLoader**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/DynamicComponentLoader-class.html) might be what you're looking for, that way you change the components internally without Routing anywhere.

Comment: `DynamicComponentLoader` is another thing I'm looking at as well.  After some trials and errors, I'm beginning to agree that we're not gonna get much out of `Router` by itself.  The `PlatformLocation` and `BrowserPlatformLocation` is pretty new and I'm trying to make sense of it as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own implementation of [`PlatformLocation`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d272f96e23f379e1b565435b3af010138e710ab9/modules/angular2/src/router/location/platform_location.ts#L25) that doesn't use `pushState()` but instead maintains the history in an array.

You can use [`BrowserPlatformLocation`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d272f96e23f379e1b565435b3af010138e710ab9/modules/angular2/src/router/location/browser_platform_location.ts#L13)

You can make Angular use your implementation by

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS, 
    MyNoUrlBrowserPlatformLocation,
    provide(PlatformLocation, {useExisting: MyNoUrlBrowserPlatformLocation})
]);
```

Comment: Is there better example about using `MyNoUrlBrowserPlatformLocation`?  I'm still studying the use of `PlatformLocation` and `BrowserPlatformLocation` but it seems pretty new and not many know how to use it yet.

Comment: `BrowserPlatformLocation` would be the example for a custom `PlatformLocation`. Otherwise I don't know. That's just the approach that I would try.